# Yarn Build Error: yarn script exited with code SIGTERM

Tags: yarnpkg

I get the **Element** repo from [github](https://github.com/vector-im/element-web/). I installed the packages and when I run `npm start` which runs `yarn build:module_system && concurrently --kill-others-on-fail --prefix "{time} [{name}]" -n res,element-js "yarn start:res" "yarn start:js"` it throughs this error:

```
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
2023-01-14 17:58:11.320 [res] yarn start:res exited with code 1
--> Sending SIGTERM to other processes..
2023-01-14 17:58:11.370 [element-js] yarn start:js exited with code SIGTERM
```

My `package.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "element-web",
    "version": "1.11.17",
    "description": "A feature-rich client for Matrix.org",
    "author": "New Vector Ltd.",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/vector-im/element-web"
    },
    "license": "Apache-2.0",
    "files": [
        "lib",
        "res",
        "src",
        "webpack.config.js",
        "scripts",
        "docs",
        "release.sh",
        "deploy",
        "CHANGELOG.md",
        "CONTRIBUTING.rst",
        "LICENSE",
        "README.md",
        "AUTHORS.rst",
        "package.json",
        "contribute.json"
    ],
    "style": "bundle.css",
    "scripts": {
        "i18n": "matrix-gen-i18n",
        "prunei18n": "matrix-prune-i18n",
        "diff-i18n": "cp src/i18n/strings/en_EN.json src/i18n/strings/en_EN_orig.json && matrix-gen-i18n && matrix-compare-i18n-files src/i18n/strings/en_EN_orig.json src/i18n/strings/en_EN.json",
        "clean": "rimraf lib webapp",
        "build": "yarn clean && yarn build:genfiles && yarn build:bundle",
        "build-stats": "yarn clean && yarn build:genfiles && yarn build:bundle-stats",
        "build:jitsi": "node scripts/build-jitsi.js",
        "build:res": "node scripts/copy-res.js",
        "build:genfiles": "yarn build:res && yarn build:jitsi && yarn build:module_system",
        "build:modernizr": "modernizr -c .modernizr.json -d src/vector/modernizr.js",
        "build:bundle": "webpack --progress --bail --mode production",
        "build:bundle-stats": "webpack --progress --bail --mode production --json > webpack-stats.json",
        "build:module_system": "tsc --project ./tsconfig.module_system.json && node ./lib/module_system/scripts/install.js",
        "dist": "scripts/package.sh",
        "start": "yarn build:module_system && concurrently --kill-others-on-fail --prefix \"{time} [{name}]\" -n res,element-js \"yarn start:res\" \"yarn start:js\"",
        "start:https": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail --prefix \"{time} [{name}]\" -n res,element-js \"yarn start:res\" \"yarn start:js --https\"",
        "start:res": "yarn build:jitsi && node scripts/copy-res.js -w",
        "start:js": "webpack-dev-server --host=0.0.0.0 --output-filename=bundles/_dev_/[name].js --output-chunk-filename=bundles/_dev_/[name].js -w --mode development --disable-host-check --hot",
        "lint": "yarn lint:types && yarn lint:js && yarn lint:style",
        "lint:js": "eslint --max-warnings 0 src module_system test && prettier --check .",
        "lint:js-fix": "prettier --write . && eslint --fix src module_system test",
        "lint:types": "tsc --noEmit --jsx react && tsc --noEmit --project ./tsconfig.module_system.json",
        "lint:style": "stylelint \"res/css/**/*.pcss\"",
        "test": "jest",
        "coverage": "yarn test --coverage",
        "analyse:unused-exports": "node ./scripts/analyse_unused_exports.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@matrix-org/olm": "https://gitlab.matrix.org/api/v4/projects/27/packages/npm/@matrix-org/olm/-/@matrix-org/olm-3.2.12.tgz",
        "@matrix-org/react-sdk-module-api": "^0.0.3",
        "gfm.css": "^1.1.2",
        "jsrsasign": "^10.5.25",
        "katex": "^0.16.0",
        "matrix-js-sdk": "github:matrix-org/matrix-js-sdk#develop",
        "matrix-react-sdk": "github:matrix-org/matrix-react-sdk#develop",
        "matrix-widget-api": "^1.1.1",
        "react": "17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "17.0.2",
        "sanitize-html": "^2.3.2",
        "ua-parser-js": "^1.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
        "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.10",
        "@babel/eslint-plugin": "^7.12.10",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.12.1",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.12.1",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.12.7",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.12.1",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.12.7",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.10",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.12.7",
        "@babel/register": "^7.12.10",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
        "@casualbot/jest-sonar-reporter": "^2.2.5",
        "@principalstudio/html-webpack-inject-preload": "^1.2.7",
        "@sentry/webpack-plugin": "^1.18.1",
        "@svgr/webpack": "^5.5.0",
        "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.5",
        "@types/flux": "^3.1.9",
        "@types/jest": "^29.0.0",
        "@types/jsrsasign": "^10.5.4",
        "@types/modernizr": "^3.5.3",
        "@types/node": "^16",
        "@types/react": "17.0.49",
        "@types/react-dom": "17.0.17",
        "@types/sanitize-html": "^2.3.1",
        "@types/ua-parser-js": "^0.7.36",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.6.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.6.0",
        "allchange": "^1.0.6",
        "babel-jest": "^29.0.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
        "chokidar": "^3.5.1",
        "concurrently": "^7.0.0",
        "cpx": "^1.5.0",
        "css-loader": "^4",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
        "eslint": "8.28.0",
        "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
        "eslint-plugin-deprecate": "^0.7.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
        "eslint-plugin-matrix-org": "^0.9.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-unicorn": "^45.0.0",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
        "fake-indexeddb": "^4.0.0",
        "fetch-mock-jest": "^1.5.1",
        "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
        "fs-extra": "^11.0.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
        "jest": "^29.0.0",
        "jest-canvas-mock": "^2.3.0",
        "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.0.0",
        "jest-mock": "^29.0.0",
        "jest-raw-loader": "^1.0.1",
        "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
        "loader-utils": "^3.0.0",
        "matrix-mock-request": "^2.5.0",
        "matrix-web-i18n": "^1.3.0",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1",
        "minimist": "^1.2.6",
        "mkdirp": "^1.0.4",
        "modernizr": "^3.12.0",
        "node-fetch": "^2.6.7",
        "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.0",
        "postcss": "^8.4.16",
        "postcss-easings": "^2.0.0",
        "postcss-hexrgba": "2.0.1",
        "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
        "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
        "postcss-mixins": "^6.2.3",
        "postcss-nested": "^4.2.3",
        "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
        "postcss-scss": "^4.0.4",
        "postcss-simple-vars": "^5.0.2",
        "prettier": "2.8.0",
        "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
        "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
        "semver": "^7.3.7",
        "simple-proxy-agent": "^1.1.0",
        "string-replace-loader": "3",
        "style-loader": "2",
        "stylelint": "^14.9.1",
        "stylelint-config-prettier": "^9.0.4",
        "stylelint-config-standard": "^29.0.0",
        "stylelint-scss": "^4.2.0",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
        "ts-prune": "^0.10.3",
        "typescript": "4.9.3",
        "webpack": "^4.46.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2",
        "worker-loader": "^3.0.0",
        "worklet-loader": "^2.0.0",
        "yaml": "^2.0.1"
    },
    "jest": {
        "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
        "testEnvironmentOptions": {
            "url": "http://localhost/"
        },
        "testMatch": [
            "<rootDir>/test/**/*-test.[tj]s?(x)"
        ],
        "setupFiles": [
            "jest-canvas-mock"
        ],
        "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
            "<rootDir>/node_modules/matrix-react-sdk/test/setupTests.js"
        ],
        "moduleNameMapper": {
            "\\.(css|scss|pcss)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/cssMock.js",
            "\\.(gif|png|ttf|woff2)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/matrix-react-sdk/__mocks__/imageMock.js",
            "\\.svg$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/matrix-react-sdk/__mocks__/svg.js",
            "\\$webapp/i18n/languages.json": "<rootDir>/node_modules/matrix-react-sdk/__mocks__/languages.json",
            "^react$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react",
            "^react-dom$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-dom",
            "^matrix-js-sdk$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/matrix-js-sdk/src",
            "^matrix-react-sdk$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/matrix-react-sdk/src",
            "decoderWorker\\.min\\.js": "<rootDir>/node_modules/matrix-react-sdk/__mocks__/empty.js",
            "decoderWorker\\.min\\.wasm": "<rootDir>/node_modules/matrix-react-sdk/__mocks__/empty.js",
            "waveWorker\\.min\\.js": "<rootDir>/node_modules/matrix-react-sdk/__mocks__/empty.js",
            "context-filter-polyfill": "<rootDir>/node_modules/matrix-react-sdk/__mocks__/empty.js",
            "FontManager.ts": "<rootDir>/node_modules/matrix-react-sdk/__mocks__/FontManager.js",
            "workers/(.+)\\.worker\\.ts": "<rootDir>/node_modules/matrix-react-sdk/__mocks__/workerMock.js",
            "^!!raw-loader!.*": "jest-raw-loader",
            "RecorderWorklet": "<rootDir>/node_modules/matrix-react-sdk/__mocks__/empty.js"
        },
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
            "/node_modules/(?!matrix-js-sdk).+$",
            "/node_modules/(?!matrix-react-sdk).+$"
        ],
        "coverageReporters": [
            "text-summary",
            "lcov"
        ],
        "testResultsProcessor": "@casualbot/jest-sonar-reporter"
    },
    "@casualbot/jest-sonar-reporter": {
        "outputDirectory": "coverage",
        "outputName": "jest-sonar-report.xml",
        "relativePaths": true
    }
}
```

Tell me if any other debug detail is needed. Thanks in advance :)